# I am getting an error with a PHP mail script

Tags: php, email

## Before Help

I am trying to setup a contact box on my website, I thought I had done this right but it seems not.

```
?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com
<script>
    type = "text/javascript" >
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function() {
        try {
            var s, a, i, j, r, c, l, b = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            l = b[b.length - 1].previousSibling;
            a = l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');
            if (a) {
                s = '';
                r = parseInt(a.substr(0, 2), 16);
                for ( j = 2; a.length - j; j += 2) {
                    c = parseInt(a.substr(j, 2), 16) ^ r;
                    s += String.fromCharCode(c);
                }
                s = document.createTextNode(s);
                l.parentNode.replaceChild(s, l);
            }
        } catch(e) {
        }
    })();
    /* ]]> */
</script>";
$subject = "JozhhDesigns You have been contacted!";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Then, The Error I Get Is:

> unexpected T_STRING in your code on line 7

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

### After Looking Over Answers

After looking through the comments, I changed some things, and now I have the following

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = 'contact@jozhhdesigns.com';
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   /* <![CDATA[ */
  (function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
$subject = 'JozhhFX You have been contacted!';
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

With this I have removed the double (") and replaced them with single (')
It is now giving me the error

```
"syntax error, unexpected '<' in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 6"
```

I know I am bad at this but any help with it?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  $recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com
  <script>
  type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
  (function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
  /* ]]> */
  </script>";
```

to

```
    $recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com";
  <script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
  (function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You close the opening script tag with the type declaration outside it.

```
<script <-- Here
type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

$recipient should be just email, Try this:

```
$recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com";
```

Here is documentation about mail function in php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Your $recipient has values with double quotes!

Try something like

```
$recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com";
$script  = <<<CDATA
<script>
type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>
CDATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes here type="text/javascript"> and here document.getElementsByTagName("script");

It will be somewhat like this type='text/javascript'> and document.getElementsByTagName('script');

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072751/write-the-email-code-for-upload-resume-in-contact-page-receive-the-email-in-php/20073275#20073275

There is some closing tag and double qoutes issue please try this

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "contact@jozhhdesigns.com";


$subject = "JozhhDesigns You have been contacted!";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```